# Java Swing MVC windows change implementation

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

Ok, so I'm trying to implement simple 2 window swing app. Basically its login window and main app window.

I have model, view controller for each. In short, code looks like this:

```
LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel();
MainModel mainModel = new MainModel();

LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();

loginController = new LoginController(loginForm, loginModel);
mainController = new MainController(mainForm, mainModel);

loginForm.setLoginListener(loginController);
```

What I'm not sure how to implement is when user provides valid credentials I dispose existing view but I'm not sure how to make visible the mainForm window. Should I pass mainForm view to loginController? What would be the best practice to implement in this case.

Comment: Shouldn't login create the main when the login is successful?

Comment: Shouldn't login just `setVisible(true)` for `main`, and `main` should be instantiated where login is instantiated?

Comment: It's up to you, my gut feeling is the `LoginController` should probably create the `MainController` in same way